# Infinitive phrase as adjective vs. adjective clause

Tags: grammar

My question is that if the below sentences have the same meaning ?

1. I cleaned my tie to look nice.
2. I cleaned my tie that looked nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No:

```
I cleaned my tie to look nice
```

Means that the reason you were cleaning your tie was because you wanted it to look nice. Or that you wanted to look nice so you cleaned your tie!

```
I cleaned my tie that looked nice
```

Means that you were cleaning a tie that already looked nice.

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: _"I cleaned my tie to look nice"_ could mean _I cleaned my tie so that **I** would look nice._  E.G.  _I dabbed on some cologne to smell nice and I cleaned my tie to look nice._

Comment: thats what i said

Comment: You said it means that _"the reason you were cleaning your tie was because you wanted **it** to look nice."_  I am saying that it might mean that the reason you were cleaning your tie was because you wanted **YOU yourself** to look nice.

Comment: Did this help you? Please upvote, if you think this was the best answer please select he check mark under the up / down vote arrows beside my answer! Thanks a ton, Glad I could help you

Comment: Does this sentence mean the same : I cleaned my tie to have looked nice.

Comment: @Marek  Short answer:  No.  Long answer.  That grammar isn't correct.  If you want details on why, ask a new question.

Comment: @Markek  No, you cant do that, what you can do is: I cleaned my tie to make sure I look nice.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so please press the checkmark below the vote up/down arrows!